# Generate and check the primality of very large numbers in Livecode

Tags: random, primes, livecode

How can I do this? All other results on these yield languages that aren't LiveCode or do not work in LiveCode for some reason. The numbers have to be randomly generated; otherwise, I could just take a few from [here](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/small2.html) (yes, ~150 digits). The end goal is to use these for encryption (a personal experiment).

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what you have done so far.  The basic method for generating a large prime is:

```
repeat
  pick a large possible prime
until (the number you picked is prime)
```

That is pseudocode since I do not know LiveCode.  You will have to do the conversion yourself.

All large primes are of the form 6n ± 1.  You can choose n in a suitable range for the size of prime you want.

For the prime testing you are going to have to convert one of the standard primality tests to LiveCode.  Alternatively, is there a way to incorporate an external method in some other language into LiveCode, which would let you copy an example from the web?

Answer (score 0):

How large are we talking here? Most programming languages use standard numeric types to store numbers internally, that are of a fixed size (e.g. 4 bytes give you numbers from about -2 billion through +2 billion).

So they're unlikely to be able to deal with numbers as large as 150 digits.

You may have to get a LiveCode plugin (external? Whatever LiveCode used to call them) that can deal with very big numbers or performs "string maths".

Answer (score 0):

Mr Devin Asay of the LiveCode use-list offers this:

```
on mouseUp
 local tNum
 put fld 2 into tNum
 put "" into fld 1
 put isPrime(tNum) into fld 1
end mouseUp

function isPrime pNum
 if pNum <> 2 AND pNum mod 2 = 0 then
  return false
 end if
 repeat with x = 3 to sqrt(pNum) step 2
  if pNum mod x = 0 then
     return false
  end if
 end repeat
 return true
end isPrime
```

The handler fails at 309 digits, due to a range (overflow) error. This is a machine limitation, not a LC one. The precision of the handler overall is limited (per Mark Waddingham of the LC team):

You can only represent integers up to around 2^53 without losing 
precision (as they are represented using IEEE doubles) which means the 
maximum number you can check for primality using this method is around 
9007199254740992.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem to deal with total perfection with number long any digits you wisk using livecode or any other language. I can work with just the + - / * operation, but I think that's is enough for your research. I made this functions:

```
function bigAdd a1, a2
  #let's check if it's negative...
  #end check
  put reverse2(a1) into b1
  put reverse2(a2) into b2
  put 0 into mem
  if length(b1) < length(b2) then
    put b1 into temp
    put b2 into b1
    put temp into b1
  end if
  repeat while b2 is not empty
    put (char 1 of b1) + (char 1 of b2) + mem into ppp
    if length(ppp) = 1 then
       put 0 into mem
       put ppp before rrr
   else
     put 1 into mem
     put char 2 of ppp before rrr
   end if
  delete char 1 of b1
  delete char 1 of b2
end repeat
repeat while (b1 is not empty)
put mem + (char 1 of b1) into ppp
if length(ppp) = 1 then
put 0 into mem
put ppp before rrr
else
put 1 into mem
put char 2 of ppp before rrr
end if
delete char 1 of b1
end repeat
if mem = 1 then
put 1 before rrr
else
put b1 before rrr
end if
return rrr
end bigAdd

function reverse2 temp
repeat for each char tChar in temp
put tChar before temp2
end repeat
return temp2
end reverse2


function bigMultiply a1,a2
put reverse2(a1) into a1
put 0 into temp
repeat for each char tChar in a1
repeat with i=1 to tChar
put bigAdd(temp,a2) into temp
end repeat
put 0 after a2
end repeat
return temp
end bigMultiply

function bigGreater a1,a2
#compare two bignumbers:
#return true if n1 > n2
#return false if n1 < n2
#return empty if n1 = n2
#let's check is a number is negative
if ((char 1 of a1 = "-") or (char 1 of a2 = "-")) then
if ((char 1 of a1 = "-") and (char 1 of a2 is not "-")) then
return false
end if
if ((char 1 of a1 is not "-") and ( char 1 of a2 = "-" )) then
return true
end if
#if we are here, both are negative
delete char 1 of a1
delete char 1 of a2
if a1 = a2 then
return empty
else
return (not bigGreater(a1,a2))
end if
end if
if length(a1) is not length(a2) then
return ( length(a1) > length(a2) ) #this is evalueted true or false
else
if a1 = a2 then
return empty
else
repeat while ((char 1 of a1) = (char 1 of a2) )
delete char 1 of a1
delete char 1 of a2
end repeat
return ((char 1 of a1) > (char 1 of a2)) #this is evalueted true or false
end if
end if
end bigGreater

function bigSub a1,a2
#substract the smallest big number from the largest one
if bigGreater(a2,a1) then
put a1 into temp
put a2 into a1
put temp into a2
end if
put reverse2(a1) into a1
put reverse2(a2) into a2
put 0 into mem
repeat while (a2 is not empty)
put (char 1 of a1) - mem + 10 - (char 1 of a2) into minus
if length(minus) = 1 then
put 1 into mem
put minus before rrr
else
put 0 into mem
put char 2 of minus before rrr
end if
delete char 1 of a1
delete char 1 of a2
end repeat
repeat while (a1 is not empty)
put char 1 of a1 + 10 - mem into minus
if length(minus) = 1 then
put 1 into mem
put minus before rrr
else
put 0 into mem
put char 2 of minus before rrr
end if
delete char 1 of a1
end repeat
#remove inital zeros
repeat while (char 1 of rrr is "0")
delete char 1 of rrr
end repeat
return rrr
end bigSub

function bigDivide a1,a2
#output is a block of two numbers "quotient , remainder"
if bigGreater(a2,a1) then
return ("0," & a1)
end if
if a1 = a2 then
return "1,0"
end if
put 0 into count
repeat while (bigGreater(a1,a2))
put bigSub(a1,a2) into a1
put bigAdd(1,count) into count
end repeat
if a1 = a2 then
put bigAdd(count,1) into count
put 0 into a1
end if
return (count & comma & a1)
end bigDivide

function bigDivide2 a1,a2
#please note that the result is "the result, the remainder"
put length(a1) into ldividendo
put length(a2) into ldivisore
if ldividendo <= ldivisore then
return bigDivide(a1,a2)
end if
put char 1 to ldivisore of a1 into tDiv
put bigDivide(tDiv,a2) into rrr
put item 1 of rrr into quoziente
put item 2 of rrr into resto
put ldivisore + 1 into nn
repeat with i = nn to ldividendo
put char i of a1 after resto
put bigDivide(resto,a2) into temp
put item 1 of temp after quoziente
put item 2 of temp into resto
end repeat
put removezeros(quoziente) into quoziente
put removezeros(resto) into resto
return (quoziente & comma & resto)
end bigDivide2

function removezeros temp
repeat while char 1 of temp is "0"
delete char 1 of temp
end repeat
return temp
end removezeros
```